# yajra Datatables filter and order data that are not in the database

Tags: laravel, sorting, datatables, filtering, yajra-datatable

Is there a way in yajra/datatables to filter and order data that are not in the Database?
I have created a column with addColumn that make the difference between 2 dates, it works fine, but i can't manage to use search and order functionality of DataTable.
Can some kind heart give me a tip?

Here is the source in the Controller

```
public function TasksData(){


    return DataTables::of(Task::query())
           ->editColumn('id', function(Task $task) {
                $link='';   
                $link .= '<a href="#">'.$task->id.'</a>';
                return $link;
            })
           ->editColumn('task_id', function(Task $task) {
                return $task->Task->name;
            })
           ->editColumn('reception_date', function(Task $task) {
               $date  = '';
               $date .= (new Carbon\Carbon($task->reception_date))->format('d/m/Y'); 
               return $date;
            })
           ->filterColumn('reception_date', function ($query, $keyword) {
               $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(reception_date,'%d/%m/%Y') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
            })
           ->editColumn('fullfilment_request', function(Task $task) {
               $date  = '';
               $date .= (new Carbon\Carbon($task->fullfilment_request))->format('d/m/Y'); 
               return $date;
            })
           ->filterColumn('fullfilment_request', function ($query, $keyword) {
               $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(fullfilment_request,'%d/%m/%Y') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
            })
           ->addColumn('days', function(Task $task) {
               $date  = '';
               $reception = Carbon\Carbon::parse($task->reception_date);
               $fullfilment = Carbon\Carbon::parse($task->fullfilment_request);
               $date .= $reception->diffInDays($fullfilment, false); 
               return $date;
            })
           ->setRowClass(function (Task $task) {
               $date  = '';
               $reception = Carbon\Carbon::parse($task->reception_date);
               $fullfilment = Carbon\Carbon::parse($task->fullfilment_request);
               $date .= $reception->diffInDays($fullfilment, false);
               return ($date < 7 && $date == 1)  ? 'bg-warning' : (($date < 0 && $date < 3) ? 'bg-danger' : '');
            })
           ->rawColumns(['id','task_id','reception_date','fullfilment_request','days'])
           ->make(true);

}
```

Comment: Post your code here or create a working fiddle or your code and provide the link here

Comment: ok added my code

Comment: [This](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/139) github issue should answer your question

Comment: @Remul Thank you. Really usefull.